# Trigger de Log que grava a numeração do JOB que executou a alteração

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Preciso de um recurso do oracle para utilizar em uma trigger, que busca qual o JOB ou  Scheduler_JOB que executou tal alteração. 
Estou usando o recurso Sys_Context para pegar algumas informações exemplo: Usuário, Terminal, Programa Etc...

```
 -- Grava as informações de rastreio
  Select substr(sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'), 1, 250),
         substr(sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), 1, 250),
         substr(sys_context('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'), 1, 250),
         substr(sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE'), 1, 250),
         substr(sys_context('USERENV', 'ACTION'), 1, 2000)

    Into vsuserbanco, vsusermaq, vsterminal, vsmodulo, vsaction
    From dual;
```

Comment: Tem dois parâmetros BG_JOB_ID FG_JOB_ID não tenho como testar agora mas parece ser um caminho.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm

Comment: Obtive o resultado necessário utilizando o FG_JOB_ID

Comment: Não consegui entender a diferença dos processos.

Comment: BG_JOB_ID busca job em segundo plano
  FG_JOB_ID busca job em primeiro plano
Quando o processo é realizado diretamente job, por exemplo um Update na tabela da  trigger vai gravar o FG_JOB_ID , se for uma procedure no JOB  que realizada toda uma logica e por fim executa um UPDATE ele vai gravar BG_JOB_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TL_MAP_PRODUTO_LOG
AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUTO
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  ------------------
  ---  VARIAVEIS ---
  Vsuserbanco VARCHAR2(250);
  Vsusermaq VARCHAR2(250);
  Vsterminal VARCHAR2(250);
  Vsmodulo VARCHAR2(250);
  Vsaction VARCHAR2(250);
  Vsuserapp VARCHAR2(250);
  V_OSUSER  VARCHAR2(50);
  V_DATA    DATE := SYSDATE;
  V_TABELA  VARCHAR2(40) := 'PRODUTO';
  V_CHAVE  VARCHAR2(20);
  V_CONTEUDO  VARCHAR2(4000);
  V_BG_JOB_ID VARCHAR2(4000);
  V_FG_JOB_ID VARCHAR2(4000);
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--BUSCA INFORMAÇÕES GERAIS DO USUARIO
SELECT Substr(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'), 1, 250),
       Substr(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), 1, 250),
       Substr(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'), 1, 250),
       Substr(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'MODULE'), 1, 250),
       Substr(Sys_Context('USERENV', 'ACTION'), 1, 250),
       Sys_Context('USERENV', 'BG_JOB_ID') Bg_Job_Id, --busca job em segundo plano
       Sys_Context('USERENV', 'FG_JOB_ID') Fg_Job_Id  -- busca job em primeiro plano
  INTO Vsuserbanco, Vsusermaq, Vsterminal, Vsmodulo, Vsaction,  V_BG_JOB_ID, V_FG_JOB_ID
  FROM Dual;

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -------> DESCRICAO 
  IF (NVL(:OLD.DESCRICAO,0) <> NVL(:NEW.DESCRICAO,0)) THEN
  V_CHAVE := :NEW.PRODUTO;
  V_CONTEUDO := 'A coluna DESCRICAO foi alterada de: '|| :OLD.DESCRICAO || ' para: ' || :NEW.DESCRICAO;
  INSERT INTO TABELA_LOG (Tabela, Chave, Data, Conteudo, Vsuserbanco, Vsusermaq, Vsterminal,   Vsmodulo, Vsaction, BG_JOB_ID,FG_JOB_ID )
                                    VALUES (V_TABELA,V_CHAVE,V_DATA,V_CONTEUDO, Vsuserbanco, Vsusermaq, Vsterminal, Vsmodulo, Vsaction,  V_BG_JOB_ID, V_FG_JOB_ID);
  END IF;
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
END;
```